# Java Restraining width for JPanel with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, combobox, gridbaglayout

I wrote a program to generate PDF tables. To make it easier to manipulate, I also created a GUI to control the things. However, It really bothers me that on JFrame, this JComboBox takes a lot of space, making the right subPanel unnecessarily wide.

The reason for this is probably that there is a **pretty long string** in the comboBox.

I tried using "set preferred size" for the panel, but it didn't work. I then proceeded to use GridBagLayout to try to narrow that combo box. Is there any way to restrict all the buttons and the comboBox to a certain width? Or should I use a different layout?

It would be best if all components in that right panel can have the same width, just like what they are now.

Thank you!

[image]

here is my code:

```
JTable studentTable=new JTable(new StudentTableModel(bro));
            studentTable.setRowHeight(25);
            studentTable.setGridColor(java.awt.Color.BLACK);
            DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new     
DefaultTableCellRenderer();
            centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

studentTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);

studentTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);

studentTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
        JPanel panelA1= new JPanel();
            panelA1.setOpaque(false);
            panelA1.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
            panelA1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JScrollPane scrollPaneA= new JScrollPane(studentTable);

        JButton buttonA1= new JButton("Activate All");

        JButton buttonA2= new JButton("Create Tables");

        JButton buttonA3= new JButton("Save File");

        JLabel labelA1= new JLabel("-Job Crews-");

        JButton buttonA4= new JButton("Deact Crew");

        JComboBox<Object> comboBoxA1=new JComboBox<Object>();
        comboBoxA1.addItem(new String("-N/A-"));
        for(JobCrew jj: crews)
        {
            comboBoxA1.addItem(jj);
        }
        comboBoxA1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,100));

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        {
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            panelA1.add(buttonA1,c);

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 1;
            panelA1.add(buttonA2,c);

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 2;
            panelA1.add(buttonA3,c);

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 3;
            panelA1.add(labelA1,c);

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 4;
            panelA1.add(comboBoxA1,c);

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 5;
            panelA1.add(buttonA4,c);

        }

        JPanel panelA= new JPanel();
            panelA.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelA,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
            panelA.setOpaque(false);
            panelA.add(scrollPaneA); panelA.add(panelA1);
        //////
        /**********/
        tabs.addTab("Student info",null,panelA,"Organizes & displays student information");
```

Comment: The size of the combobox (by default) is equal to the width of the longest element, this makes it so that the combobox and corresponding popup are the same size ... why, I'd know - probably so when you select an item, it's not truncated.  If you do a [google search for "java jcombobox popup width"](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+jcombobox+popup+width&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=-Ru_WdK2Donp8wfowpiQDA) you'll find that this is not a uncommon problem - the problem (that I've found) is finding a solution that works consistently

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for your advice. However, although I get what you are saying, I am hoping that the popup width can be larger than the combobox width. I think changing the popup width isn't really going to help?

Comment: Have a look at the results from the google search, they focus on making the combobox smaller then the popup window, which will always been the size of the longest item ... which based on my understanding of your question, seems to be what you're trying to fix - again though, I've never found a solution which is consistent across platforms or JVMs

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I tried what you and the replier below said and it works perfectly now! I just used this link https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/ and it seems like a universal solution to this problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Combo Box Popup](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/).

[image]

It will allow you to control the width of the combo box itself and the popup can be the full width.

Or you can set a property so that a scrollbar will be displayed in the popup if required.